# Whats wrong with my code? The backwards loop doesnt work (Option 2)

Tags: slider, controls, frequency

The option (2) crashes/overloads my coding software, it has the same code as option (1), does anybody know why its doing it and how to fix it?

```cpp
#include "aservelibs/aservelib.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int length();
float mtof(int note);

int main() {
    // do while the user hasnt pressed exit key (whatever)
    int control[8] = {74, 71, 91, 93, 73, 72, 5, 84};
    int index;
    int mod;
    float frequency;
    int notes[8];
    int response;

    mod = aserveGetControl(1);

    // ask backwards, forwards, exit

    // SCALING
    // (getControl(75) / ((127 - 0) / (1000 - 100))) + 100;
    while(true) {
        printf("Run Loop Forwards (1), Backwards (2), Exit (0)\n");
        scanf("%d", &response);
        if(response == 1) {
            while(mod == 0) {
                for(index = 0; index < 8; index++) {
                    notes[index] = aserveGetControl(control[index]);
                    frequency = mtof(notes[index]);
                    aserveOscillator(0, frequency, 1.0, 0);
                    aserveSleep(length());
                    printf("Slider Value:%5d\n", notes[index]);
                    mod = aserveGetControl(1);
                }
            }
        } else if(response == 2) {
            // here is the part where the code is exactly
            // the same apart from the for loop which is
            // meant to make the loop go backwards

            while(mod == 0) {
                for(index = 8; index > 0; index--) {
                    notes[index] = aserveGetControl(control[index]);
                    frequency = mtof(notes[index]);
                    aserveOscillator(0, frequency, 1.0, 0);
                    aserveSleep(length());
                    printf("Slider Value:%5d\n", notes[index]);
                    mod = aserveGetControl(1);
                }
            }
        } else if(response == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

int length() {
    return (aserveGetControl(75)/((127.0 - 0) / (1000 - 100))) + 100;
}

float mtof(int note) {
    return 440 * pow(2, (note-69) / 12.0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loops aren't exactly the same.

The first option goes through { 0, 1, ..., 7 }

The second option goes through { 8, 7, ..., 1 }

Notice also that control[8] is undefined (0..7). So when it tries to reference this location the application runs into an error.

Change the second for loop to

```
for (index = 7; index >= 0; index--) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks alot! helped me get out of the rut! always forget that 0 counts as a number..